# Several menus, functions for hiding and hiding, code review AngularJS, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I did functions to show and hide menus, but I think that it can be saved shorter.

Can someone make code review and tell me how can I Make it a nicer code, and which will better work? Please.

And can you do it differently with closing the menu than adding action to the body

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.toggle = false;

    $scope.activeMenu = function (name, toggle) {
        $scope.name = name;
        $scope.toggle = toggle;
        console.log(name, toggle);
    }
});
```

template:

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-click="name = ''; toggle = false;" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="account-item">
        <div class="account-heading">
            <h4 class="account-title">
                <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="activeMenu('Home', !toggle);$event.stopPropagation() "> Home </a>
            </h4>
            <div class="menu" ng-click="activeMenu('Home', true);$event.stopPropagation() " ng-class="{active : name === 'Home' && toggle === true}">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="activeMenu('Home', false);$event.stopPropagation() ">close</a>
                    <li>Home</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="account-item">
        <div class="account-heading">
            <h4 class="account-title">
                <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="activeMenu('Contact', !toggle);$event.stopPropagation() "> Contact </a>
            </h4>
            <div class="menu" ng-click="activeMenu('Contact', true);$event.stopPropagation() " ng-class="{active : name === 'Contact' && toggle === true}">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="activeMenu('Contact', false);$event.stopPropagation(); toggle=false; ">close</a>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {{name}} {{toggle}}
</body>
```

**DEMO**

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/jGjyyw

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea and a better approach

```js
(function(app) {
  app.controller('Ctrl', function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.setTab = function(tabId) {
      this.tab = tabId;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabId) {
      return this.tab === tabId;
    };
  });
})(angular.module('App', []));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{ active: vm.isSet(1) }">
      <a href ng-click="vm.setTab(1)">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: vm.isSet(2) }">
      <a href ng-click="vm.setTab(2)">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-show="vm.isSet(1)">
    <h4>Home</h4>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="vm.isSet(2)">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just mean that I have what I want, but I want to write it nicer in the code, can u help me??

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska read the AngularJS [style guide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1)

Comment: thanks, but... this is my task for tomorrow, I will not make it on time if i will start read it, can u only tell me what do with this code? i dont need ready solution, i need only direction